# Getting Exception when using a CircularCountdown custom view in android

Tags: android, android-custom-view

> Getting Exception when using a CircularCountdown custom view in android, added code below
>
> MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.jayakarthik.sampleanim;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

> activity_main.xml
>
> added custom view CircularCountdown

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.example.jayakarthik.sampleanim.CircularCountdown
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> CircularCountdown.java
>
> CircularCountdown Custom View

```
package com.example.jayakarthik.sampleanim;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.view.View;

public class CircularCountdown extends View {

        private final Paint backgroundPaint;
        private final Paint progressPaint;
        private final Paint textPaint;

        private long startTime;
        private long currentTime;
        private long maxTime;

        private long progressMillisecond;
        private double progress;

        private RectF circleBounds;
        private float radius;
        private float handleRadius;
        private float textHeight;
        private float textOffset;

        private final Handler viewHandler;
        private final Runnable updateView;

        public CircularCountdown(Context context) {
            super(context);

        // used to fit the circle into
        circleBounds = new RectF();

         // size of circle and handle
         radius = 200;
         handleRadius = 10;

          // limit the counter to go up to maxTime ms
          maxTime = 5000;

           // start and current time
          startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
          currentTime = startTime;


            // the style of the background
            backgroundPaint = new Paint();
            backgroundPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            backgroundPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            backgroundPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
            backgroundPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.SQUARE);
            backgroundPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#4D4D4D"));  // dark gray

            // the style of the 'progress'
            progressPaint = new Paint();
            progressPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            progressPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            progressPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
            progressPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.SQUARE);
            progressPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00A9FF"));    

            // the style for the text in the middle
            textPaint = new TextPaint();
            textPaint.setTextSize(radius / 2);
            textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

            // text attributes
            textHeight = textPaint.descent() - textPaint.ascent();
            textOffset = (textHeight / 2) - textPaint.descent();


            // This will ensure the animation will run periodically
            viewHandler = new Handler();
            updateView = new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
         // update current time
         currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

         // get elapsed time in milliseconds and clamp between <0, maxTime>
        progressMillisecond = maxTime - (currentTime - startTime) % maxTime;

        // get current progress on a range <0, 1>
        progress = (double) progressMillisecond / maxTime;

        CircularCountdown.this.invalidate();
         viewHandler.postDelayed(updateView, 1000/60);
             }
            };
            viewHandler.post(updateView);
        }



        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // get the center of the view
        float centerWidth = canvas.getWidth() / 2;
        float centerHeight = canvas.getHeight() / 2;


         // set bound of our circle in the middle of the view
         circleBounds.set(centerWidth - radius,
          centerHeight - radius,
           centerWidth + radius, 
           centerHeight + radius);


           // draw background circle
           canvas.drawCircle(centerWidth, centerHeight, radius, backgroundPaint);

           // we want to start at -90°, 0° is pointing to the right
           canvas.drawArc(circleBounds, -90, (float)(progress*360), false, progressPaint);

           // display text inside the circle
          canvas.drawText((double)(progressMillisecond/100)/10 + "s",
          centerWidth, centerHeight + textOffset,
          textPaint);

          // draw handle or the circle
           canvas.drawCircle((float)(centerWidth  + (Math.sin(progress * 2 * Math.PI) * radius)),
           (float)(centerHeight - (Math.cos(progress * 2 * Math.PI) * radius)),
           handleRadius,
           progressPaint);
        }

    }
```

> Log

```
08-19 13:03:13.662    3700-3700/com.example.jayakarthik.sampleanim E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.jayakarthik.sampleanim, PID: 3700
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jayakarthik.sampleanim/com.example.jayakarthik.sampleanim.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.example.jayakarthik.sampleanim.CircularCountdown
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2301)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5212)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.example.jayakarthik.sampleanim.CircularCountdown
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:603)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:294)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at com.example.jayakarthik.sampleanim.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5240)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2216)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2301)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5212)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:446)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:568)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:294)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at com.example.jayakarthik.sampleanim.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5240)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2216)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2301)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5212)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init>`

Answer (score 3):

The constructor called when the view is inflated by the xml is

```
public View (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
```

so you need to add your

```
public CircularCountdown (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
   super(context, attrs);
}
```

and move intialize the subclass members also from this constructor